# I can't seem to pass an array of objects as prop (console logs 1 object, [object object] instead)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React js and I am trying to pass my data(dummy_data) as props from App.js to PieChart.js so that I can access the data from PieChart.js. dummy_data is an array of objects, dummy_data={[object Object] [object Object] ... [object Object]}.

I am confused as to why I am only able to see 1 object pair from my console log in PieChart, [object Object]. What do I need to do to pass the dummy_data object array to my PieChart function in PieChart.js?

I have tried the passing of a normal array the syntax , but my console log in PieChart.js still shows me the same output [object Object]. Am I using the syntax wrongly?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// imports
import PieChart from './components/piechart'; // Piechart for dashboard

/*
Info:
"data" contains all MongoDB data read from /api call, which uses find({ }) to search MongoDB for all data.
"data" is an array of objects in the format Data: { [object object], [object object] ... [object object] }
getInOutEnv(item) {} is used to map the "data" retrieved from /api call. The resulting response allows me to
access each object in "data" as "item" and accessing the object's properties using item (item.environment and item.lightlevel)
*/

// app class
class App extends React.Component {

  // Accessing values/var from functions
  dummy = []; // store response data from /api (server/MongoDB)
  dummy_final = []; // store previous data of dummy and check to see if they hold the same values
  map = [];   // store data in mapped format to be able to access object properties (e.g. trythis.env and trythis.lightlv)
  
  getInOutEnv(item) {
    console.log( 'obj - ' + [item.environment,item.lightlevel].join(" ") );
    let inOut = {env: item.environment, lightlv: item.lightlevel};
    return (inOut);
  }

  getData() {
    axios.get('/api')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data; //contains all the data from MongoDB
        console.log('---------- <Get Data> ----------');
        console.log(`data : ${data}`);
        console.log(`map : ${this.map}`);
        // try 1
        this.dummy = data;  // data and dummy are an array of objects -> Data: { [object object] [object object] ... [object object]}
        console.log(`[dummy] ${this.dummy}`);
        let map = this.dummy.map(this.getInOutEnv);
        console.log('----- accessing obj properties -----')
        if (JSON.stringify(this.dummy) !== JSON.stringify(this.dummy_final)) {
          console.log(`[dummy] ${JSON.stringify(this.dummy)}`);
          console.log(`[dummy_final] ${JSON.stringify(this.dummy_final)}`); // check if difference between dummy and dummy_final
          ...
            //increase count of lightlv
            switch(trythis.lightlv) { // 6 cases 'Bright', 'Dark', 'Normal', 'VerySunny', 'Outcast', 'Sunny'
              ...
            }
          }
          // set dummy to dummy_final, so this loop will not trigger unless new data is fetched to dummy from /api (MongoDB)
          this.dummy_final = this.dummy;
          console.log(`[new dummy_final] ${JSON.stringify(this.dummy_final)}`);
        } else {
          console.log('[Data stored is up to date] Values of MongoDB matches current data stored in dummy_final');
          console.log(`[Current Env Indoor] ${this.envCount_Indoor}`);  // check count of env indoor
          console.log(`[Current Env Outdoor] ${this.envCount_Outdoor}`);  // check count of env outdoor
          console.log(`[Current Env Mismatched Field Names] ${this.envCount_Error}`);  // check count of mismatched Field Names
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('Error in retrieving data');
      });
  }

  render() {

    this.getData();
    console.log(`[testingData] ${this.dummy_final}`);

    return(
        <div className="App">
          Pie Chart
          <PieChart dummy_final={this.dummy_final}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

PieChart.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Pie, Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart, ArcElement } from "chart.js";
Chart.register(ArcElement);


// chart background colour for env
const bgcolour_env = [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',  //colour 1...
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',  
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'   //last colour
]

const hover_env = [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.8)',  //colour 1...
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.8)',  
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.8)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.8)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.8)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.8)'
]

// chart background for lightlevel

const data = {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: bgcolour_env,
        hoverBackgroundColor: hover_env
    }]
}

function PieChart({dummy_final}) {
  let data1 = [];
  data1 = dummy_final;
  console.log(`dummy_final : ${dummy_final}`);
  //console.log(`data1 : ${JSON.stringify(data1)}`);

  return (
      <div>
        test
        <Doughnut 
        data={data}
        options={{
          title:{
            display:true,
            text:'Average Rainfall per month',
          },
          legend:{
            display:true,
            position:'right'
          }
        }}
        />
      </div>
  );
}
  
export default PieChart;
```

Comment: Update, I figured out that the problem was actually with my `dummy_final` array being empty. Does anyone knows how I can retrieve my 'completed' `dummy_final` array from getData()? Because I think my `dummy_final` is currently empty because it is declared `dummy_final = [];` above. (and maybe the getData function has yet to finish its process before my `console.log(`[testingData] ${this.dummy_final}`);` which is why the dummy_final is logging `dummy_final = [];`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About useEffect, if you'd look the link that I left on my comment, you'd see that it combines two class methods componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, actually it has componentWillUnmount there too, try something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import PieChart from './components/piechart'; // Piechart for dashboard

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      environment: '',
      lightlevel: '',
      data_form: [],
    };
  }

  getData() {
    axios.get('/api')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data; //contains all the data from MongoDB
        this.setState({
          data_form: data,
        }); 
      })
      .catch((error) => alert('Error in retrieving data', error));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    console.log(`did mount [state data] ${this.state.data_form}`);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.getData();
    console.log(`did update [state data] ${this.state.data_form}`);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        Pie Chart
        <PieChart data_form={this.state.data_form}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Can't test it myself without the project, but I think it should work.

**UPDATE: (SAME CODE WITH FUNCTIONAL COMPONENTS)**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// import from components
import PieChart from './components/piechart'; // Piechart for dashboard

function App()  {
  const [dataForm, setDataForm] = useState([]);

  getData() {
    axios.get('/api')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setDataForm(data); 
      })
      .catch((error) => alert('Error in retrieving data', error));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
    console.log(`will be called once on first render [state data]: ${dataForm}`);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Pie Chart
      <PieChart data_form={dataForm}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: BTW, is there any reason why you're using class components instead of function  components?

Comment: Thank you @I-vasilich-I for the suggestion I will try out the answer you suggested. May I know if the `componentDidUpdate` will automatically update the state if there is a change in data? The reason why I am using class instead of functions is because I followed a tutorial when I first started on how to use `MERN` stack to connect to MongoDB and creating forms with React.

Comment: If you have some extra time to spare could you help me explain briefly or link me to the comparison between class vs functional components? (I have seen a number of tutorial and realised that both are quite widely used. I also read thru the React Docs briefly before starting but, I think I might need some simple examples to learn better along the way.)

Comment: first thing you need to do is to read React Docs, at least main concepts and hooks parts it'll answer questions that you ask here. As for class vs function components - it's easier to learn function component, class components are used a lot, but all new staff written mainly with functional component, with hooks. Don't understand why people tend to skip docs

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html 
React component: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html
componentDidUpdate: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: I have tried the didComponentUpdate and didComponentMount method and it works, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE!**

I realised that using `setState` here would actually be easier to pass the data and is the more ideal way of passing my data since it is part of the React Lifecycle (still have no clue how to pass a promise's returned data).

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

// import from components
import PieChart from './components/piechart'; // Piechart for dashboard

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      environment: '',
      lightlevel: '',
      data_form: []
    };
  }


  // Accessing values/var from functions
  dummy = []; // store response data from /api (server/MongoDB)
  dummy_final = []; // store previous data of dummy and check to see if they hold the same values


  getData() {
    return axios.get('/api')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data; //contains all the data from MongoDB
        this.dummy = data;
        console.log(`[data] : ${data}`);
        console.log(`[check dummy] ${this.dummy}`);
        console.log('---------- <Get Data> ----------');
        // Checking if dummy and dummy_final have the same data. If they do, do not retrieve data. If not retrieve and set data.
        if (JSON.stringify(this.dummy) !== JSON.stringify(this.dummy_final)) {
          this.setState({
            data_form: this.dummy
          });
          console.log('Reached');
          this.dummy_final = this.dummy;
          console.log(`[dummy_final] ${this.dummy_final}`);
        } else {
          console.log('Data up to date');
          console.log(`[Current Data] ${this.dummy_final}`);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('Error in retrieving data');
      });
  }


  render() {

    this.getData();

    console.log(`[state data] ${this.state.data_form}`);


    //JSX
    return(
        <div className="App">
          Pie Chart
          <PieChart data_form={this.state.data_form}/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Since you cannot call upon `useEffect` in Class Component, I just used a conditional statement to compare `this.dummy` and `final_dummy` after assigning `this.dummy` to my `response.data` from my /api call, at the start since `this.dummy` will be assigned `response.data`, the conditional statement returns false, thereby triggering the function to `setState` with `this.dummy` as the data and assigning `this.dummy` to `this.dummy_final`. After which since calling a useState will result in an **infinite render loop**, I fixed this with the conditional statement such that will since `this.dummy` is now = `this.dummy_final`, the condition is false and will not trigger the setState conditional block, thereby preventing an infinite loop. (This method is basically just replicating useEffect hook in Component Class without encapsulating a functional component)

PieChart.js

```
import React from "react";

function PieChart(props) {
  console.log(`data_form : ${props.data_form}`);
  ...


  return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
  );
}
  
export default PieChart;
```

Hope this helps anyone who ran into the same issue starting React without an experience.

Feel free to leave some links to some useful information about the latest React workflow. I would greatly appreciate it, Cheers!

Comment: you can use class component methods that was there before useEffect (still there) https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-classes
haven't used class components, but I think calling this.getData() inside render method is a very bad idea

Comment: @I-vasilich-I Do you mean calling `useEffect` within my `getData()` function? I was thinking of using `componentDidMount`, correct me if I am wrong but I think `componentDidMount` triggers only once at the start of the runtime? I want to make sure that my data updates will re-render the page as well which is why I was thinking how to use `useEffect`, currently I am not sure how to do that maybe a post will help for `useEffect` regarding my use case. The solution I came to was as shown above, just calling `setState` if the data is changed (but this is done manually without `useEffect`).